# uvcvideo driver issue : Failed to query (GET_INFO) UVC control

Tags: usb, camera

There is a issue for my usb camera,

```
sudo journalctl -b |grep UVC
Feb 04 17:04:58 mydebian kernel: uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device HIK 1080P CAMERA (2bdf:0284)
Feb 04 17:04:58 mydebian kernel: uvcvideo: Failed to query (GET_INFO) UVC control 12 on unit 2: -32 (exp. 1).
Feb 04 17:04:58 mydebian kernel: uvcvideo: Failed to query (GET_INFO) UVC control 11 on unit 2: -32 (exp. 1).
```

It can be found by my os,why Failed to query (GET_INFO) UVC control 12 on unit ?
I paste the output piece of `lsusb -v`  related with usb camera.

```
lsusb -v 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 2bdf:0284  
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass          239 Miscellaneous Device
  bDeviceSubClass         2 
  bDeviceProtocol         1 Interface Association
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x2bdf 
  idProduct          0x0284 
  bcdDevice           10.02
  iManufacturer           1 
  iProduct                2 
  iSerial                 3 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x028d
    bNumInterfaces          5
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xc0
      Self Powered
    MaxPower              200mA
    Interface Association:
      bLength                 8
      bDescriptorType        11
      bFirstInterface         0
      bInterfaceCount         2
      bFunctionClass         14 Video
      bFunctionSubClass       3 Video Interface Collection
      bFunctionProtocol       0 
      iFunction               4 
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass        14 Video
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Video Control
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              4 
      VideoControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                13
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      1 (HEADER)
        bcdUVC               1.00
        wTotalLength       0x0033
        dwClockFrequency       48.000000MHz
        bInCollection           1
        baInterfaceNr( 0)       1
      VideoControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                18
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      2 (INPUT_TERMINAL)
        bTerminalID             1
        wTerminalType      0x0201 Camera Sensor
        bAssocTerminal          0
        iTerminal               0 
        wObjectiveFocalLengthMin      0
        wObjectiveFocalLengthMax      0
        wOcularFocalLength            0
        bControlSize                  3
        bmControls           0x00002200
          Zoom (Absolute)
          Roll (Absolute)
      VideoControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                11
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      5 (PROCESSING_UNIT)
      Warning: Descriptor too short
        bUnitID                 2
        bSourceID               1
        wMaxMultiplier      16384
        bControlSize            2
        bmControls     0x000017df
          Brightness
          Contrast
          Hue
          Saturation
          Sharpness
          White Balance Temperature
          White Balance Component
          Backlight Compensation
          Gain
          Power Line Frequency
          White Balance Temperature, Auto
        iProcessing             0 
        bmVideoStandards     0x09
          None
          SECAM - 625/50
      VideoControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      3 (OUTPUT_TERMINAL)
        bTerminalID             3
        wTerminalType      0x0101 USB Streaming
        bAssocTerminal          0
        bSourceID               2
        iTerminal               0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0010  1x 16 bytes
        bInterval               8
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           0
      bInterfaceClass        14 Video
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Video Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                            15
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                  1 (INPUT_HEADER)
        bNumFormats                         2
        wTotalLength                   0x018f
        bEndPointAddress                  136
        bmInfo                              0
        bTerminalLink                       3
        bStillCaptureMethod                 2
        bTriggerSupport                     1
        bTriggerUsage                       1
        bControlSize                        1
        bmaControls( 0)                     0
        bmaControls( 1)                     4
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                            11
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                  6 (FORMAT_MJPEG)
        bFormatIndex                        1
        bNumFrameDescriptors                5
        bFlags                              0
          Fixed-size samples: No
        bDefaultFrameIndex                  1
        bAspectRatioX                       0
        bAspectRatioY                       0
        bmInterlaceFlags                 0x00
          Interlaced stream or variable: No
          Fields per frame: 1 fields
          Field 1 first: No
          Field pattern: Field 1 only
        bCopyProtect                        0
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                            34
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                  7 (FRAME_MJPEG)
        bFrameIndex                         1
        bmCapabilities                   0x00
          Still image unsupported
        wWidth                            640
        wHeight                           480
        dwMinBitRate                  7372800
        dwMaxBitRate                  7372800
        dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize      460800
        dwDefaultFrameInterval         333333
        bFrameIntervalType                  2
        dwFrameInterval( 0)            333333
        dwFrameInterval( 1)            400000
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                            34
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                  7 (FRAME_MJPEG)
        bFrameIndex                         2
        bmCapabilities                   0x00
          Still image unsupported
        wWidth                           1920
        wHeight                          1080
        dwMinBitRate                  7372800
        dwMaxBitRate                  7372800
        dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize      460800
        dwDefaultFrameInterval         333333
        bFrameIntervalType                  2
        dwFrameInterval( 0)            333333
        dwFrameInterval( 1)            400000
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                            34
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                  7 (FRAME_MJPEG)
        bFrameIndex                         3
        bmCapabilities                   0x00
          Still image unsupported
        wWidth                           1280
        wHeight                           960
        dwMinBitRate                  7372800
        dwMaxBitRate                  7372800
        dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize      460800
        dwDefaultFrameInterval         333333
        bFrameIntervalType                  2
        dwFrameInterval( 0)            333333
        dwFrameInterval( 1)            400000
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                            34
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                  7 (FRAME_MJPEG)
        bFrameIndex                         4
        bmCapabilities                   0x00
          Still image unsupported
        wWidth                           1280
        wHeight                           720
        dwMinBitRate                  7372800
        dwMaxBitRate                  7372800
        dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize      460800
        dwDefaultFrameInterval         333333
        bFrameIntervalType                  2
        dwFrameInterval( 0)            333333
        dwFrameInterval( 1)            400000
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                            34
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                  7 (FRAME_MJPEG)
        bFrameIndex                         5
        bmCapabilities                   0x00
          Still image unsupported
        wWidth                            640
        wHeight                           480
        dwMinBitRate                  7372800
        dwMaxBitRate                  7372800
        dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize      460800
        dwDefaultFrameInterval         333333
        bFrameIntervalType                  2
        dwFrameInterval( 0)            333333
        dwFrameInterval( 1)            400000
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                            10
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                  3 (STILL_IMAGE_FRAME)
        bEndpointAddress                    0
        bNumImageSizePatterns               1
        wWidth( 0)                       1920
        wHeight( 0)                      1080
        bNumCompressionPatterns             0
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                            27
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                  4 (FORMAT_UNCOMPRESSED)
        bFormatIndex                        2
        bNumFrameDescriptors                5
        guidFormat                            {32595559-0000-0010-8000-00aa00389b71}
        bBitsPerPixel                      16
        bDefaultFrameIndex                  1
        bAspectRatioX                       0
        bAspectRatioY                       0
        bmInterlaceFlags                 0x00
          Interlaced stream or variable: No
          Fields per frame: 2 fields
          Field 1 first: No
          Field pattern: Field 1 only
        bCopyProtect                        0
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                            30
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                  5 (FRAME_UNCOMPRESSED)
        bFrameIndex                         1
        bmCapabilities                   0x00
          Still image unsupported
        wWidth                            640
        wHeight                           480
        dwMinBitRate                 29491200
        dwMaxBitRate                 29491200
        dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize     1843200
        dwDefaultFrameInterval         333333
        bFrameIntervalType                  1
        dwFrameInterval( 0)            333333
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                            30
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                  5 (FRAME_UNCOMPRESSED)
        bFrameIndex                         2
        bmCapabilities                   0x00
          Still image unsupported
        wWidth                           1920
        wHeight                          1080
        dwMinBitRate                 29491200
        dwMaxBitRate                 29491200
        dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize     1843200
        dwDefaultFrameInterval         333333
        bFrameIntervalType                  1
        dwFrameInterval( 0)           1999998
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                            30
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                  5 (FRAME_UNCOMPRESSED)
        bFrameIndex                         3
        bmCapabilities                   0x00
          Still image unsupported
        wWidth                           1280
        wHeight                           960
        dwMinBitRate                 29491200
        dwMaxBitRate                 29491200
        dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize     1843200
        dwDefaultFrameInterval         333333
        bFrameIntervalType                  1
        dwFrameInterval( 0)           1999998
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                            30
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                  5 (FRAME_UNCOMPRESSED)
        bFrameIndex                         4
        bmCapabilities                   0x00
          Still image unsupported
        wWidth                           1280
        wHeight                           720
        dwMinBitRate                 29491200
        dwMaxBitRate                 29491200
        dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize     1843200
        dwDefaultFrameInterval         333333
        bFrameIntervalType                  1
        dwFrameInterval( 0)           1999998
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                            30
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                  5 (FRAME_UNCOMPRESSED)
        bFrameIndex                         5
        bmCapabilities                   0x00
          Still image unsupported
        wWidth                            640
        wHeight                           480
        dwMinBitRate                 29491200
        dwMaxBitRate                 29491200
        dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize     1843200
        dwDefaultFrameInterval         333333
        bFrameIntervalType                  1
        dwFrameInterval( 0)            333333
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                            10
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                  3 (STILL_IMAGE_FRAME)
        bEndpointAddress                    0
        bNumImageSizePatterns               1
        wWidth( 0)                       1920
        wHeight( 0)                      1080
        bNumCompressionPatterns             0
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                             6
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                 13 (COLORFORMAT)
        bColorPrimaries                     1 (BT.709,sRGB)
        bTransferCharacteristics            1 (BT.709)
        bMatrixCoefficients                 4 (SMPTE 170M (BT.601))
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       1
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass        14 Video
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Video Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x88  EP 8 IN
        bmAttributes            5
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               Asynchronous
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x1400  3x 1024 bytes
        bInterval               1
    Interface Association:
      bLength                 8
      bDescriptorType        11
      bFirstInterface         2
      bInterfaceCount         2
      bFunctionClass          1 Audio
      bFunctionSubClass       0 
      bFunctionProtocol       0 
      iFunction               5 
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        2
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           0
      bInterfaceClass         1 Audio
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Control Device
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              5 
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      1 (HEADER)
        bcdADC               1.00
        wTotalLength       0x0027
        bInCollection           1
        baInterfaceNr(0)        3
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                12
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      2 (INPUT_TERMINAL)
        bTerminalID             2
        wTerminalType      0x0201 Microphone
        bAssocTerminal          0
        bNrChannels             1
        wChannelConfig     0x0003
          Left Front (L)
          Right Front (R)
        iChannelNames           0 
        iTerminal               0 
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      3 (OUTPUT_TERMINAL)
        bTerminalID             4
        wTerminalType      0x0101 USB Streaming
        bAssocTerminal          0
        bSourceID               6
        iTerminal               0 
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      6 (FEATURE_UNIT)
        bUnitID                 6
        bSourceID               2
        bControlSize            2
        bmaControls(0)     0x0003
          Mute Control
          Volume Control
        iFeature                0 
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        3
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           0
      bInterfaceClass         1 Audio
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        3
      bAlternateSetting       1
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         1 Audio
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      AudioStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      1 (AS_GENERAL)
        bTerminalLink           4
        bDelay                  1 frames
        wFormatTag         0x0001 PCM
      AudioStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                11
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      2 (FORMAT_TYPE)
        bFormatType             1 (FORMAT_TYPE_I)
        bNrChannels             1
        bSubframeSize           2
        bBitResolution         16
        bSamFreqType            1 Discrete
        tSamFreq[ 0]        16000
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes           13
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               Synchronous
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0180  1x 384 bytes
        bInterval               4
        bRefresh                0
        bSynchAddress           0
        AudioStreaming Endpoint Descriptor:
          bLength                 7
          bDescriptorType        37
          bDescriptorSubtype      1 (EP_GENERAL)
          bmAttributes         0x01
            Sampling Frequency
          bLockDelayUnits         1 Milliseconds
          wLockDelay         0x0001
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        4
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              6 
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.01
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength      35
         Report Descriptors: 
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0400  1x 1024 bytes
        bInterval               4
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0400  1x 1024 bytes
        bInterval               4
```